# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 0

Tags: python, django, celery, python-unicode

I looked at a number of the answers to similar questions, but can't seem to see where the error is occurring in my code. The error occurs when I try to run celery: `celery –A runLogProject worker –loglevel=INFO`. I commented out all the code related to Celery and it gives the same error. I also tried reinstalling Celery. I'm not sure what else to try. Here is the traceback:

```
 C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py:803: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both
arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if len(argv) > 1 and 'worker' in argv[0:3]:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py:765: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both
arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if 'multi' in argv[1:3]:  # Issue 1008
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py:398: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both ar
guments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if '--version' in argv:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\celery.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 769, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 304, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 435, in setup_app_from_commandline
    preload_options = self.parse_preload_options(argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 500, in parse_preload_options
    return self.preparse_options(args, self.preload_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 512, in preparse_options
    if arg.startswith('--'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: You have to provide some code to get accurate solution to your problem.

Comment: The challenge is that all the code in the traceback is within the Celery source. I have looked at the lines referenced and can't determine where it's being called. I have also commented out sections of my code (and all of the celery dependent code) and receive the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure what issue you mention here (please provide link to issue number) but take a look on my answer below. It looks like this is only weird typo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's tricky issue. The problem is in how you typed your command:

Wrong:

```
celery –A runLogProject worker –loglevel=INFO
```

Correct:

```
celery -A runLogProject worker -loglevel=INFO
```

It's almost impossible to spot a difference. In first to pass parameters -A and -loglevel are used dashes (ascii code: 8211) but should by hyphens (ascii code 45).

If you are using OSX, it could be triggered because you pressed ALT together with hyphen/minus key or you just copy pasted it from some blog which uses weird autocorrect.

Comment: That was it! I had copied the command into a word document for documentation and copy/pasted that version. Thanks for catching it. I can include that in the instructions.

Comment: Never use Word or any other rich text documents. Cope/paste your code using IDEs or simple code editors.

Comment: How can the above be right?  Wouldn't that need to be `--loglevel=INFO`  Note two hyphens?  (Also I'm typing this in manually and still getting the ascii error, but at least I know where the problem comes from.  Note also that my same command was working in Python 2.7.10 but now in 3.7.3, not so much...